# Status 200 ok but no json rendered using grails web service

Tags: json, web-services, grails, amazon-ec2

I'm using grails to generate a JSON and generate URL..
when I try to access the URL..
it gets connected..as in STatus is coming out to be 200 ok
but there is no response..

Anyone knows how to fix this issue..
Please help

Thanks..

Using amazon ec-2 but it's not even working locally..
So the problem is with grails mapping only..
anyone knows what can be the issue here..
?

Comment: If you get a status, then there _is_ a _response_, just no _response body_. In any case, please post the code that is handling the request.

Comment: code??I'm new to grails so.dont' know what to post..ther is no use of putting controller code as controller is working fine..and url mapping is fine too..are there any config files that need to be manipulated..??

Comment: If you are getting a 200 response, then Grails is successfully mapping the request to a controller and responding. The issue, as I understand from your question, is that there is no _response body_ and the only way to figure out what is going on is to inspect both the request/response pair, as well as the code that is handling the request (which, in this case, should be a controller action). And since you are not getting the response you expect, it's _possible_ that your controller _isn't_ working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to keep the html files in the same server under the same folder...
working fine..
before it was a cross platform issue..